# Create absolute url from relative url in drupal

Tags: url, drupal-7

I have created an update script in **hook_update_N** where I have to create relative urls from absolute url.

*For eg :*

`relative url = /files/test1.jpg`

```
absolute url should be http://localhost.mysite/files/test1.jpg
```

I know these possible solutions,

- file_create_url()
- url()
- $_SERVER['host'], $_SERVER['server_name']

But none of them is working in the update script.

*Possible Reason* : Script isn't executed from browser. So there isn't request from which you can resolve server name etc.

The above solutions work fine if I run the script from browser instead of terminal.

Is there any other way we can create absolute urls in hook_update_N so that it works when I run the script from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use global $base_url and add to it your relative url

```
global $base_url;
$full_url = $base_url . $relative_url
```